# Azure B2C for front-end + daemon application

Tags: spring, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a tenant and application to be able to authenticate users via Azure B2C. I have a front-end application in React which uses Msal.js with authorization grant to obtain the access token, which is then used to make requests to a webserver which acts as a resource-server (connected to Azure b2c as well). I have used this answer to make it work -> [How to secure Spring Boot REST API with Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628114/how-to-secure-spring-boot-rest-api-with-azure-ad-b2c)

Apart from that I have few daemon applications which need to connect to the backend as well. They should use client_crendentials grant_type to connect to the backend server (which is a resource-server).

However, the token that is obtain by the daemon app, cannot be used with the backend server (resource server) for some reason. Is there something that I do wrong ? Do you have samples for this scenario ? I've already spent days looking over all the documentation to find where is the problem.

Comment: What endpoints did you use in the daemon app to obtain a token for your backend services. Technically you need to use Azure AD token endpoint (since it’s the one that supports client credentials) and that means your backend needs to trust tokens from AAD and AAD B2C. Probably it only trusts B2C issued tokens right now.

Comment: @JasSuri thanks a lot for your reply! I am using the following endpoint from the daemon app - https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

Indeed, my backend it needs to trust both AAD B2C and AAD tokens. I am currently using the following config to trust the AAD B2C tokens :

```spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri: https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-id>/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=<sign-in-policy>
```
Any idea how to configure backend to trust both AAD and AAD B2C tokens ?

Comment: start here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5385 and here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7857

Comment: @GeorgePlaton Any luck with that? I have the same issue