# Validate token which sent by front end

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

I have front end(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa) with azure ad b2c. After user login, azure AD return token for SPA. I call a springboot api with this access token.

How my springboot app can validate acess token and get user information from azure ad b2c with this token.

Thanks!

Comment: Spring Boot would use Spring Security to validate and authenticate and authorise the interaction based on the token, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#introduction

Answer (score 1):

This [sample](https://github.com/My-Azure-Projects/AzureActiveDirectoryApplication) can meet your requirements.

It uses Azure Active Directory B2C to authenticate users into a single page application (SPA). Then return the access token and id token, and then use the access token to call the Spring Boot application. The backend will verify the access token and return user information.

Comment: I think this repo is same with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628114/how-to-secure-spring-boot-rest-api-with-azure-ad-b2c.

But, there is no authority.

Comment: I think there is no authentication in springboot backend. Because i can paste any token from azure ad.